# ¿Como puedo mostrar en mi tabla el estado activo o inactivo en php?

Tags: php

[image: En mi tabla , tengo un campo activo que muestra 1 y 0 .]

> El codigo. Quisiera que en vez de 1 y 0 , se mostrata Activo o Inactivo. Les agradeceria su ayuda.

```
$cadena .= '
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <th class="col-sm-2">CODIGO</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">NOMBRE</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">TELEFONO</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">DIRECCION</th>
            <th class="col-sm-1">ACTIVO </th>
            <th class="col-sm-1">CONTRIBUYENTE </th>
            <th class="col-sm-1">EDITAR</th>
            <th class="col-sm-1">BORRAR</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';
        while ($fila = $establecimientos->fetch_array()) {
             $cadena .= '
                <input type="hidden" id="nombre'.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].'" value="'.$fila['nombre'].'">
                <input type="hidden" id="telefono'.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].'" value="'.$fila['telefono'].'">
                <input type="hidden" id="direccion'.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].'" value="'.$fila['direccion'].'">
                <input type="hidden" id="activo'.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].'" value="'.$fila['activo'].'">
                <input type="hidden" id="idContribuyente'.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].'" value="'.$fila['idContribuyente'].'">
                <tr>
                    <td class="info">'.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].'</td>
                    <td class="success">'.$fila['nombre'].'</td>
                    <td class="success">'.$fila['telefono'].'</td>
                    <td class="success">'.$fila['direccion'].'</td>

                    <td>
                        if($fila['activo']==1){
                            echo $act='ACTIVO';
                        } else {
                            echo $act='INACTIVO';
                        }
                    </td>

                    <td class="success">'.$fila['razonsocial'].'</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="editarEstablecimiento" data-target="#eModalEstablecimiento" data-toggle="modal" value="editar" onclick="editarEstablecimiento('.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].')">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" onclick="borrarEstablecimiento('.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].')" class="btn btn-danger" id="borraEstablecimiento" value="borrar">
                    </td>                       
                </tr>';
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'activo' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Restaurante\php\paginacionestablecimientos.php on line 53

```
    <td class="info">'.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].'</td>
                    <td class="success">'.$fila['nombre'].'</td>
                    <td class="success">'.$fila['telefono'].'</td>
                    <td class="success">'.$fila['direccion'].'</td>

                    <td>
                        if($fila['activo']==1){
                            echo $act='ACTIVO';
                        } else {
                            echo $act='INACTIVO';
                        }
                    </td>

                    <td class="success">'.$fila['razonsocial'].'</td>
```

Comment: Lo más simple y claro sería usar *operador ternario* (como señala @MarceloZarate), y si es posible evitar la horrible mezcla PHP/HTML concatenando y guardando en variables las constantes llamadas a elementos como `$fila['indice']`.

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que hacer el **if** antes de llamar a la variable **$cadena** y luego la incrustas en esa tabla así:

```
while ($fila = $establecimientos->fetch_array()) {

  if($fila['activo']==1){
    $act='ACTIVO';
  } else {
    $act='INACTIVO';
  }

   $cadena .= '<input type="hidden" id="nombre'.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].'" value="'.$fila['nombre'].'">
               <input type="hidden" id="telefono'.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].'" value="'.$fila['telefono'].'">
               <input type="hidden" id="direccion'.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].'" value="'.$fila['direccion'].'">
               <input type="hidden" id="activo'.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].'" value="'.$fila['activo'].'">
               <input type="hidden" id="idContribuyente'.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].'" value="'.$fila['idContribuyente'].'">
                <tr>
                    <td class="info">'.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].'</td>
                    <td class="success">'.$fila['nombre'].'</td>
                    <td class="success">'.$fila['telefono'].'</td>
                    <td class="success">'.$fila['direccion'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$act.'</td>
                    <td class="success">'.$fila['razonsocial'].'</td>
```

Al final quedaría así:

```
<td>'.$act.'</td>
```

Comment: Solucionado. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Estás alternando entre una cadena (string) y sentencias php, deberías probar algo así, empleo [operador ternario](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) por una cuestión de simplicidad

```
$cadena .= '
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th class="col-sm-2">CODIGO</th>
        <th class="col-sm-2">NOMBRE</th>
        <th class="col-sm-2">TELEFONO</th>
        <th class="col-sm-2">DIRECCION</th>
        <th class="col-sm-1">ACTIVO </th>
        <th class="col-sm-1">CONTRIBUYENTE </th>
        <th class="col-sm-1">EDITAR</th>
        <th class="col-sm-1">BORRAR</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';
    while ($fila = $establecimientos->fetch_array()) {
         $cadena .= '
            <input type="hidden" id="nombre'.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].'" value="'.$fila['nombre'].'">
            <input type="hidden" id="telefono'.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].'" value="'.$fila['telefono'].'">
            <input type="hidden" id="direccion'.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].'" value="'.$fila['direccion'].'">
            <input type="hidden" id="activo'.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].'" value="'.$fila['activo'].'">
            <input type="hidden" id="idContribuyente'.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].'" value="'.$fila['idContribuyente'].'">
            <tr>
                <td class="info">'.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].'</td>
                <td class="success">'.$fila['nombre'].'</td>
                <td class="success">'.$fila['telefono'].'</td>
                <td class="success">'.$fila['direccion'].'</td>

                <td>'.echo ($fila["activo"]==1) ? "ACTIVO" : "INACTIVO".'</td>

                <td class="success">'.$fila['razonsocial'].'</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="editarEstablecimiento" data-target="#eModalEstablecimiento" data-toggle="modal" value="editar" onclick="editarEstablecimiento('.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].')">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" onclick="borrarEstablecimiento('.$fila['idpuntoestablecimiento'].')" class="btn btn-danger" id="borraEstablecimiento" value="borrar">
                </td>                       
            </tr>';
```

Comment: Solucionado. Muchas gracias por la ayuda y tiempo.